# Microsoft Access - Insert part of a string up until a specific character

Tags: string, ms-access, vba

I'll keep this simple:

I have three textboxes and a button.
**textbox1** is used as user input

**button1** is pressed and this gives **textbox2** and **textbox3** a specific value based on the string from **textbox1**.

For example- User input: '**Hello & welcome everybody**'

***Press button**

**textbox2.Value** = 'Hello'

**textbox3.Value** = 'welcome'

So basically, how do I go about selecting part of a string up until a certain character?

And also, how do I go about selecting part of a string between a certain character/words (In this case, between '**&**' and '**everybody**'

I know I could dim two variables as strings to store them, then set the value of the textboxes to equal the variables. But I don't know what code to use to obtain the specific parts of the string in the first place. Any ideas?

Comment: string operations: locate the `&`, then grab everything up to that location.

Comment: You didn't explain the logic behind the splitting. By character? (if so, always "&"?) Or split at spaces? -- Useful functions: Instr, Left, Mid, Split

Comment: @Andre I'd split the string at the '&', then remove any additional spaces. I'm just not sure what function to use to grab the whole string up until that character; and how to format the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Split Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-Function-876f246a-5144-44fa-889f-10078c7878f5) to split the string on the `&` character, returning an array of the resulting substring pieces.

Here is an example from the Immediate window:

```vb
strUserinput = "Hello & welcome everybody"
varPieces = Split(strUserinput, "&")
Debug.Print Trim(varPieces(0))
Hello
Debug.Print Trim(varPieces(1))
welcome everybody
```

Since you want just *"welcome"* instead of *"welcome everybody"*, you can `Split()` again:

```vb
Debug.Print Split(Trim(varPieces(1)), " ")(0)
welcome
```

However it looks simpler to just `Split()` on the spaces in the first place and then take the first and third items from the array.  (Thanks, [Johnny Bones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272703/microsoft-access-insert-part-of-a-string-up-until-a-specific-character/35273219?noredirect=1#comment58258319_35273219)!):

```vb
varPieces = Split(strUserinput, " ")
? varPieces(0)
Hello
? varPieces(2)
welcome
```

Comment: This is almost perfect - if I wanted to just grab 'welcome' instead of 'welcome everybody' - would I have to make another variable and assign it like so:   Anothervariable = Split(varPieces, "everybody")

Comment: That, or split on the " " and use varPieces(0) and varPieces(2).

Comment: Oops, didn't notice you want just "welcome" there.  My bad.  Fixed.

Comment: I think the answer is satisfactory for your specific example, but I'm unsure whether it would still be so if you have 2 words before the `&`.  Could you have an input like *"Hello World & welcome everybody"*?  If so, what should be extracted then?

Comment: @HansUp Hi, your answer is perfect for what I need, in combination with Johnny's suggestion. For my specific database I would want everything before the & to be extracted into it's own string. So if it was "Hello World & Welcome Everybody", then I would want:

"Hello World" and "Welcome"; which works fine with the example you provided :-)